# how to fetch file from remote repository on bitbucket using go language

Tags: go, bitbucket

I have latest file which is on remote bitbucket repo.
I need use Go language program in that I need to fetch above file from "go get" is this possible ?
How to write code in go language to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to write any go code for this, just do:

```
go get <bitbucket repo URL>
```

Make sure that the URL is public so `go get` can work. Bear in mind that to use this package, you need to import in in your `main.go` program.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, actually if the repo is git then it is fine, if it is suppose bitbucket then again one more tool need to install instead of that any other way ? I mean for bitbucket need to install - go: missing Mercurial command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd